# Cygwin/Git on Win hangs after a while after large(?) amount of cURL POST requests are pasted at once into terminal

Tags: windows, git, terminal, cygwin, freeze

I need to consecutively execute 300 or 600 or more `cURL` POST requests. I have them in plain text, and I simply copy-paste into the terminal.

But regardless which one I use, Cygwin or Git on Windows, the following occurs:

- If I paste 300 into the terminal, it'll consecutively execute around 104, and then it'll start hanging. Can't stop it or type anything, a complete freeze that lasts forever.

[image]

- But if I paste 200 into the terminal, all will be consecutively finished with success.

Not sure which details I should provide that could prove to be the bottleneck here, so for a start I would only say that ONE command contains ~1270 characters.

Be kind to provide a solution to be able to consecutively execute even 2000 such `cURL` POST requests with "one paste" into terminal.

Comment: Note: [`curl/curl` issue 5784](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/5784#issuecomment-722017659) has been closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Be kind to provide a solution to be able to consecutively execute even 2000 such cURL POST requests with "one paste" into terminal.

I would do:

- one paste in an editor, to save those calls as a script
- one call to that script in the shell.

That way, you can accommodate any number of call in your bash (Git or Cygwin) session, by executing one script which was filled with "one paste".

The OP confirms however that the issue persists, which could be linked to `curl` itself, as in [`curl/curl` issue 5784: "`curl` stops execution/"hangs" after random time"](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/5784) (Aug. 2020).
However, that issue just got closed (Nov. 2020), with [Daniel Stenberg](https://github.com/bagder) [commenting](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/5784#issuecomment-722017659):

> I don't see anything for us to act on in this issue.
> It's not even clear that this is curl's fault. And nothing has been added to the case in months.
> Because of all this, I'm closing.

Comment: I was expecting that answer, but due to lack of knowledge and experience it was nice for someone like you to actually confirm it as a solution before I learn how to do it practically for the first time. Thank you for the upvote & edit & answer, dear VonC.

Comment: @Elio You are most welcome. I would rather rely on script than giant copy-paste. It seems safer.

Comment: The paste is fully completed I can see an already known variable at the last request but 100+ and it halts. So anything that won't cause a freeze is welcome. Thank you once again for your time and help.

Comment: @Elio Do you mean the script execution itself freezes?

Comment: precisely, you'd see what's shown on the screenshot, the thing masked with red is the last (let's say the 103th in a row) cURL POST request that was executed successfully, but instead of proceeding executing the 104th... I just get what is shown on the screenshot and it stays that way forever (I can manually confirm by checking elsewhere that nothing is being executed in background), you can't type anything or ctrl+z it, complete freeze. AND TO REPEAT.... that would happen if I paste 300 requests at once in the terminal, but not 200 for an example. I confirmed that multiple times.

Comment: What kind of remote server are you addressing those curl to? There could be some kind of limit on the server side.

Comment: Even I can say one of the most reliable in the world probably hah :) Allow me to point again: Paste 300 in terminal, it'll freeze at 104. But paste 200 and all 200 will be properly executed. I don't know the technical term but when you paste X requests in a terminal for a consecutive execution at interval of Y seconds between each, the terminal puts them "in queue" (buffer ?), and then executes them one by one. Unlike 104/300, 200/200 always passes so it couldn't be the server, but the problem lies in Cygwin/Git itself ? ...or something in the Win itself ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222120/discussion-between-vonc-and-elio).

Comment: A script did the trick, for 600+ at least, presumably it will work for 3x that as well. Thank you once again.